# exec-maven-plugin 1.6.0 Could not find or load main class

Tags: maven, spring-boot, exec-maven-plugin

I want to execute a java program during my maven build, so I have in my POM:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <executable>java</executable>
            <addResourcesToClasspath>true</addResourcesToClasspath>
            <arguments>
                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                <classpath />
            <argument>com.cnp.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication</argument>
                <argument>--server.port=${tomcat-port}</argument>
                    ...
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It was all working fine when I have used Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE, but today I switch to Spring Boot 2.1, it does not work and the error is:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default) ---

Error: Could not find or load main class com.cnp.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:804)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:751)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Could anyone give me a hint what can I do to solve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: in `<configuration>` try to add : `<mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>` ?
You can take a look in https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: doesn't work. Reading from the error message, I think it is clear the main class is com.cnp.codegenerator.CodeGeneratorApplication, so it does not make sense to specify again.

Comment: Why would you like to use exec-maven-plugin for a spring boot application? You don't need it. The spring-boot-maven-plugin produces a full running jar file etc. So I don't understand your need to use exec-maven-plugin?

Comment: I have to generate some code by calling another service duing maven clean package. That is why I need exec-maven-plugin to call the code generation application.